# Editing the saved user profile in django

Tags: django

I created a registration form with django user model with adding an extra field confirm_pwd. I created a edit page for editing the details of a particular user.After editing i need to display the profile details in the profile page.I created profile page also.But it is displaying only when the user registered or logged in only.When i click the save button after editing the details it is redirected to profile page.At this time the profile page doesn't displaying the details.Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import UserProfileInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_pwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password']
    help_texts={
        'username': None
    }
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(EditProfileForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_pwd")
    print(confirm_password)

    if password != confirm_password:
        print("yes")
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
        )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .models import UserProfileInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm,GithubInfo,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:profile'))
    else:
        form=EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "signupapp/edit_profile.html", {'form':form })
```

edit_profile.html

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

profile.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<h3>Firstname: {{ user.first_name }}</h3>
<h3>Lastname: {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
<h3>Username: {{ user.username }}</h3>
<h3>Email: {{ user.email }}</h3>
<a href="{% url 'signupapp:edit' %}"><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' request.user.id %}"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a><br>
<br>
{% else %}
<h3>Register or Login if you'd like to</h3>
{% endif %}
```

When i run this code in sever, the profile page doesn't displaying the user details.

How can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` you're getting `user` from `request.user` and trying to assign a new value to `confirm_pwd`. However, `user` doesn't have `confirm_pwd`. That `user` is the Django User and not your UserProfileInfo. By removing the line below on your `views.py` it should work. Besides you don't need to save the password confirmation, that should be only for checking purposes.

```py
# to be removed
user.confirm_pwd = request.POST['confirm_pwd']
```

Comment: The error is not located at the `user.confirm_pwd = ...`, in fact that would be no problem at all, since it will dynamically add an extra attribute. It is located at the `user.confirm_pwd` in the `initial={...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a lot of logic yourself, that a `ModelForm` should handle. One of the main purposes of a `ModelForm` is exactly to create and edit model objects without a lot of boilerplate logic.

It is not clear why you use a second form at all. Especially since you do not render it, nor do you do much with it. So it might make more sense to drop that form.

Your `EditProfileForm` does contain a super call to with a class that is not a superclass of that class, you should use `super(ModelForm, self)`, instead of <s>`super(UserForm, self)`</s>.

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ModelForm, self).clean()
        # ...
        return cleaned_data
```

The main problem is that you initialize the form with:

```
pform = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST or None, initial={'confirm_pwd': user.confirm_pwd})
```

since a `user` has no `confirm_pwd` field or attribute or property.

Furthermore a `User` model does *not* save raw passwords. These passwords are hashed to avoid a hacker to inspect passwords if they manage to access the database.

You can implement your view with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return redirect('signupapp:profile')
    else:
        form=EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "signupapp/edit_profile.html", {'form':form })
```

It would probably be better to patch the `__init__` of your `EditProfileForm`, since now it will initialize the password field with the hashed version of the password. This is thus different than the password that was entered, and furthermore it exposes some data in the database that should probably be kept safe.

Comment: By doing like this it's showing error   TypeError at /edit/
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: @BinduMachani: that's because of your `cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")` line, your form is not a `UserForm`, but a `ModelForm`.